$p$-powers in a purely inseparable extension
I have the following problem. If $k \subset K \subset L$ are finite purely inseparable field extensions of characteristic $p >0$, do we have necessarily that $$ (kK^p) \cap L^p = K^p \: ? $$ ($kK^p$ is the subfield of $L$ generated by $k$ and $K^p$.)
If $k \subset K^p$ it is trivial.
If $k$ and $L^p$ are linearly independent over $k^p$, then the equality is also true. Indeed, one can take a $k$-basis $(e_1,\cdots,e_m)$ of $K/k$ and complete it into a basis $(e_1,\cdots,e_n)$ of $L/k$. Then $(e_1^p,\cdots,e_m^p)$ is a $k^p$-basis of $K^p$ and $(e_1^p,\cdots,e_n^p)$ is a $k^p$-basis of $L^p$. Now because of the hypothesis, the family $(e_1^p,\cdots,e_n^p)$ is still linearly independent over $k$. So, given an element $x \in (kK^p) \cap L^p$, it can be written as \begin{align*} x & = \lambda_1 e_1^p +\cdots+\lambda_m e_m^p  \in kK^p\\
& = \alpha_1^p e_1^p+\cdots + \alpha_m^p e_m^p + \cdots + \alpha_n^p e_n^p \in L^p
\end{align*} for scalars $\lambda_i$, $\alpha_j \in k$, and since  $(e_1^p,\cdots,e_n^p)$ is $k$-linearly independent, one finds that $\alpha_{m+1} = \cdots=\alpha_n =0$, thus $x \in K^p$.
If you have any idea or some reference that can helps, you're welcome !

Let $k=\Bbb F_p(x,y), K=\Bbb F_p(x^{1/p},y), L=\Bbb F_p(x^{1/p},y^{1/p})$.Then $L/K/k$ are purely inseparable, $K^p = \Bbb F_p(x,y^p)\subseteq k$, but $kK^p\cap L^p = k\cap k=k\ne K^p$.

Yes, indeed ! But actually I forgot to give some hypotheses I didn't think necessary... You can check the general question ! link
